# Jiggling a gameobject in Unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

How do I make a gameobject like a sphere to jiggle in space, meaning rapidly moving around in random directions while holding it's original position.

I know I can come up with some really long codes to kind of simulate this but I was wondering if there is a trick to it.

Thanks

Comment: How can something move around while holding it's position?

Comment: How about animating it instead of actually moving it?

Comment: Not holding it's position but staying at the same spot while jiggling.

Comment: Animation is a good idea actually, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want are joints. You can attach a [spring joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html) component to a gameObject with a rigidbody. On the spring joint, set the connected body to a seperate gameObject with a kinematic rigidbody, then play with the spring joint settings until you get a nice jiggle effect. Probably increase the Spring value a bunch.

Comment: Thanks for the input I will try this, I never worked with spring joints before but I guess I have to get into it.